# Yii2 подскажите, можно ли реализовать поиск по ключевому слову

Tags: yii2

Подскажите, кто хорошо знаком с Yii2, можно ли используя ActiveSearch реализовать поиск по ключевому слову. Я пока нашёл только такой способ, но мне он не особо нравится:

```html
// Получаем названи таблиц
$couponsTable = Coupons::tableName();
$clubProfileTable = ClubProfile::tableName();

// Поиск по ключевому слову
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'like', 
    'concat('
    . "`$couponsTable`.title, `$couponsTable`.description, "
    . "`$clubProfileTable`.city, `$clubProfileTable`.address"
    . ')', 
    $this->keyword
]);
```

Comment: В yii2 нет сущности `ActiveSearch`. Во фреймворке существуют ORM-ы для [Sphinx Search](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-sphinx) и [Elasticsearch](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-elasticsearch), которые наследуются от базового `BaseActiveRecord`, а также можно использовать DBAL/Query builder вместо ORM `ActiveRecord`. Пока я вижу, что вы используете тупо "LIKE", а желательно полнотекстовый поиск. У вас какая РСУБД, MySQL?

Comment: [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) созданный Андреем Аксёновым и [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) - это поисковые движки (индексаторы), которые могут работать в паре с СУБД (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoDB и т.д.). В общем, необходим навык в [их настройке](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-sphinx/blob/master/tests/data/sphinx/sphinx.conf).

Answer (score 1):

Без конкатенации:

```
$query->orWhere(['like', "{{{$couponsTable}}}.[[title]]", $this->keyword])
  ->orWhere(['like', "{{{$couponsTable}}}.[[description]]", $this->keyword])
  ->orWhere(['like', "{{{$clubProfileTable}}}.[[city]]", $this->keyword])
  ->orWhere(['like', "{{{$clubProfileTable}}}.[[address]]", $this->keyword])
```

С конкатенацией:

```
$query->andWhere(['like', "CONCAT ({{{$couponsTable}}}.[[title]], {{{$couponsTable}}}.[[description]], {{{$clubProfileTable}}}.[[city]], {{{$clubProfileTable}}}.[[address]])", $this->keyword]])
```

Экраниврование имён таблиц и стобцов в ORM/DBAL yii2 осуществляется: `{{<имя_таблицы>}}` и `[[<имя_столбца>]]`. Сделано это для удобной миграции/портировании на другие СУБД.

Как только вы мне скажите какая у вас СУБД (вижу только, что не postgres), посмотрим что можно сделать с полнотекстовым поиском.

Comment: Я использую СУБД - MySQL